# Data center vs Data warehouse

Tags: web-server, database, web-hosting, datacenter, data-warehouse

I've heard both of these terms used frequently. What is the difference between a Data center vs. a Data warehouse? Are these terms interchangeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may wish to check out Wikipedia on [Data Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_center) and [Data Warehouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Warehouse)

> A data center or datacenter (or datacentre), also called a server farm,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_center) is a facility used to house computer systems and associated components, such as telecommunications and storage systems.

and

> Data warehouse is a repository of an organization's electronically stored data. Data warehouses are designed to facilitate reporting and analysis

Also a Data Warehouse may host many [Data Marts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mart)

> A data mart is a subset of an
>   organizational data store, usually
>   oriented to a specific purpose or
>   major data subject, that may be
>   distributed to support business needs.

So there can be **one or more Data Marts**, that exist **in a Data Warehouse** that is **hosted in a Data Center** that may contain more than one Data Warehouse plus other services.

Comment: +1 for noticing Wikipedia has an entry for each.

Comment: +1 thanks for introducing me to data marts... I often wondered about portions of data that companies (read Google) could sell

Answer (score 2):

A [data center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_center) is a physical facility where (usually) multiple companies' computers are located.  It is often so that servers can have a larger-bandwidth Internet connection than the company can get in their own facility, as well as having people dedicated to facilities management, including cooling, power, fire prevention, security, etc.

A [data warehouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse) is a type of database, or a manner of using a database, to collect large amounts of data.

They are not even remotely interchangeable terms.